# Density of a image measure

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega,A,\mu)$ be a measure space. For a mapping $T: \Omega \to \Omega$ which together with its inverse is an measurable bijection. I want to show that for every $f$ measurable non negative holds the following
\begin{equation*}
T(f\mu) = (f \circ T^{-1})T(\mu).
\end{equation*}

So, this is what i have tried, but i think that I'm not getting anywhere.

Let $g$ a measurable non negative function, then trying to prove the equality using integrals i start with the left side
\begin{align*}
\int g dT(f\mu) &= \int g \circ T d(f\mu) \\
&= \int(g \circ T)\cdot fd\mu.
\end{align*}
And this is the part where i tried writing like $T\circ T^{-1}$ or keep using some ideas of integration of image measure but does not seem to reach something. So i know it probably seems like i have not done too much work, but i have already tried a lot, so any hints or any help would be really helpfull.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what means the expressions $f\mu$ and $T(\mu)$?

Comment: $T(\mu)$ is the image measure and $f\mu$ is density of a measure, suppose we have $v = f\mu$ for a measure $v$ then for any set A $v(A) = \int_A f d\mu$

Comment: sorry but the notation is still confusing, if $T(\mu)=\mu \circ T^{-1}$ then, what means the expression $(f\circ T^{-1})T(\mu )$? It must be understood that $f\circ T^{-1}$ is the density of the measure defined by $T(\mu )$?

Comment: Ya, it's just what u said

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of unfolding the definitions correctly. On the one hand we have

$$T(f\mu)(A):=(f\mu)(T^{-1}(A)):=\int_{T^{-1}(A)} f d\mu$$

On the other hand the transformation theorem implies that

$$(f \circ T^{-1})T(\mu)(A):=\int_A f \circ T^{-1} dT(\mu)=\int 1_A(f \circ T^{-1}) dT(\mu)$$
$$=\int 1_A(f \circ T^{-1}) \circ T  d\mu=\int_{T^{-1}(A)} f \circ T^{-1} \circ T d\mu$$
$$=\int_{T^{-1}(A)} fd\mu$$